# Passing data back from ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im using bootstrap 3 tabs. So I've got multiple hashed URL's. There is a form in each of the hashed url's.:

```
example.org/documents
example.org/documents#home
example.org/documents#policies
example.org/documents#memos
```

I'm trying to return data from an ajax call to one hashed url based on what the url was the form was submitted. Right now data is passed to all the hashed url's. How can I make a form submitted in

> example.org/documents#home

show the data passed back, and not to the rest of the hashed url's.

All data from each form is being passed back to this span under each form:

```
<span class="responds"></span>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$("form#contact").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formdata = new FormData(this);
        $(".load-image").show();
        $.ajax({
                url: "php/upload.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                mimeTypes: "multipart/form-data",
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
            })
            .done(function(msg) {
                $(".responds").after(msg);
                $(".load-image").hide();
            })
            .fail(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#LoadingImage").hide();
            })
    });`
```

is there a way to pass the hashed url in my form then pass it back to the .responds class?

Here is the form:

```
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
<h3>Main</h3>
<ul class="list-group">
    <?php $files = glob('docs/*.{pdf}', GLOB_BRACE); ?>
    <?php foreach ($files as $file): ?>
    <?php $filename = $file; ?>
    <?php $vars = multiexplode(array('docs/', '.pdf'), $file); ?>
    <br>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $file; ?>">
            <span class="pull-right label label-default">
                <?php echo date ("n/j/y", filemtime($filename)); ?>
            </span>
            <?php foreach ($vars as $var): ?>
            <?php echo $var; ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </a>
        <?php if (true == in_array($idUser, $admin)): ?>
        <form id="deleteFile" class="delete pull-left" action="php/deleteFile.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" value="../<?php echo $file; ?>" name="file" id="file">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link btn-md" style="padding:0 5px 0 0; ">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
        </form>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </li>
    <span class="responds"></span>
    </ul>
    <?php if (true == in_array($idUser, $admin)): ?>
    <form id="contact" class="contact" action="php/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div><b>Select a file to upload:</b></div>
        <input type="hidden" value="../docs/" name="location" id="location">
            <label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" value="" id="file">
            </label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="file_name">New File Name (optional)</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="new_name" placeholder="ESD 5 Handbook 11-2016" aria-describedby="file_name">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="file_name">.pdf</span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" id="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i> Upload File
            <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw load-image" id="LoadingImage" style="display:none"></i>
        </button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div class="alert" style="margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 5px;"></div>
    <p class="bg-info">
        Upload a new file. .pdf files only. Rename the file to according to how it is displayed. ie <code>Sample Document.pdf</code>
    </p>
    <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: `documents` is your page. Hashtags are just anchors on the same page. I think instead of `$(".responds").after(msg);` you're simply looking for `$(this).after(msg);` (or use `$(this).parent().find('.responds').after(msg);`).

Comment: how do i load the response into the .responds class using $(this)

Comment: `$(this)` refers to the element that you're calling the function from. That way you can isolate out the elements that all have a class of `response`, and only add the response to the relevant element. As for how to use `$(this)`, I literally gave you exactly the code you should need. If it doesn't work, you'll need to provide your HTML.

Comment: Yeah, its not working man. Its not putting a response anywhere.

Comment: `<span class="responds"></span>
    </ul>` looks invalid. Where does the ul start? Where are the "li" elements that should be inside it. You can't put a span directly inside a ul. Once your HTML is valid, if it still doesn't work then check whether your ajax call is definitely firing the "done" callback and not the "fail" callback? Check your console / network tab for ajax errors. And check that "msg" actually contains some valid HTML content.

Comment: Seems like $(this) isn't able to find the element. If i use $('*') it updates all .responds spans.

Comment: Had to declare `var span = $(this);` Did it for me. Thanks OA for pointing me in the right direction.